# Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired on background third party API call

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I have Sidekiq 5 workers, concurrency 50. My webapp make third party API calls every few minutes, averagely 15000 requests per hour. Each hour I have near 10 errors `Net::OpenTimeout: execution expired`. Looks like not a big problem, but I want to know how to deal with it. Thanks.

```
def grabber(url)
    response, body = nil
    uri = URI(url)
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
                    :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', :read_timeout => 1000) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

      response = http.request request
    end
    if response.code == '200'
      body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
    body
  end
```

Comment: increase the read_timeout? increase your bandwidth if possible?

Comment: @maxpleaner how to understand what value of read_timeout will be ok? or by experiments only?

Comment: Basically yeah, by experiments. I'm figuring the value is a number of milliseconds, and the 1000 means 1 second

Comment: @maxpleaner I'd increase it to 8000 ms, but qtt of errors didn't change

Answer (score 2):

Net::HTTP throws an exception when request time out occurs.

You can just catch exceptions and do something with it:

```
rescue Net::OpenTimeout
  #do something
```

[Here](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html) you can get some examples.